# iphone - custom UIAlertView block effect

Tags: ios, block, effect, alertview

I am making a custom alertView similar like standard alertView in iOS.

for making block effect , I did this

```
UIView * backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
backgroundView.alpha = 0.4f;
[view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

it works similar like showing standard alert.

but It doesn't works in Tabbar's Area.

How do I ?

[**Before showing alert View**]
[image]
[**standard alertView Image**]
[image]

[**cutom alertView Image**]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add backgroundView to UIWindow and bring backgroundView to front.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:backgroundView]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add backgroundView on the top.

```
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[mainWindow addSubview: backgroundView];
```